# Processing ASCII commands via RS232 in embedded c

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded

I have an RS232 interface to my microcontroller with a predefined set of commands. There are several hundred commands, e.g. `PRESSURE 50` could be set pressure to 50; `LIMIT 60` could be set some limit to 60.

Current, this is processed using a series of nested switch statements but this seems like an inelegant solution.

What would be the recommended / most efficient / most readable way to process these commands? A LUT would be the tidiest, but would surely have a lot of empty entries for letter combinations which don't exist (not ideal..).

Thanks for any ideas..

Comment: In the past I've broken this task up into two parts: a lexical scan and then syntax parsing.  The lexical scanner converts the input text into tokens.  Each space-separated word is sequentially compared to an alphabetized list of same-length keywords.  A match produces a token value.  Digits get converted to a number token and a binary value.  The parsing uses `switch` and `if` statements  Check a how-to-write-a-compiler book for other ideas.

Comment: This sounds like it would optimise efficiency, but would really sacrifice maintainability - I want to make this as developer-error-proof as possible so having separate arrays sorted by command string length sounds like asking for trouble..

Comment: In order to scratch your reductionist itch, see [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).  The `lexer` will basically make tables that are 256 entry state machines.  I imagine that `strnstr()` is doing something similar.  *Boyer-Moore* is faster than `bsearch()` as you can skip characters.  Consider *cat*, *cab*, and *car*.  If the first char matches **c**, then check the third character and skip the 2nd.  A *lexer* can also do this for multiple strings.

Comment: *"...but would really sacrifice maintainability"* -- The key point is to separate lexical (string comparison) from syntax processing. A separate lexical scan allows for internationalization or synonyms for commands.  The focus is on the tokens.  Organizing/maintaining the string arrays is trivial.  Maybe if all you ever plan on parsing is of the form <keyword><numeric arg>, then this is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run-time proposal:

   With a sorted array of struct { string, function pointer )

   - sorted by [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)
   - retrieved by [bsearch()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/)

   I hope `qsort()` and `bsearch()` are available in your platform (`stdlib.h`)
2. Design-time proposal:

   As comments suggest, it's better to sort the entries of the array initialization at design-time. A lot of ways exists, from code generation (luxurious) to macro processing (poor).

   Suggestion of declaration, one into many:

   ```
   typedef unsigned char byte;

   typedef char commandId_t[40];

   typedef void (*commandHandler_t)( const byte * payload );

   typedef struct command_s {
      const commandId_t      commandId;
      const commandHandler_t handler;
   } command_t;

   static const command_t commands[] = {
   #include "sortedCommandInitializers"
   };
   ```

   The file `sortedCommandInitializers` is a list of `{"command-name", function-name},` which may be sorted by the command `sort CommandInitializers.c > sortedCommandInitializers` in the Makefile.

   For `make` it's a dependencies like any other:

   ```
   sortedCommandInitializers: CommandInitializers.c
       sort CommandInitializers.c > sortedCommandInitializers

   myProgram.o: myProgram.c myProgram.h sortedCommandInitializers
   ```

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do the sort at compile time, or failing that only once on startup, so speed wouldn't really matter.

Comment: That's true, sort at design-time is more efficient but requires a good process, at boot-time it may be acceptable.

Comment: This does seem like a nice, **easy to read**, solution - how would you implement the sort at compile time in C?

Comment: This is the option I went with in the end, since it seemed to enhance readability as well. Many thanks to all who contributed ideas!

Answer (score 3):

Ever tried the strnstr function? It really is very fast. For a few 100 words, it would probably be faster then 8 or 9 separate strcmp() with some extra code in between to walk through a tree, and will need less memory to store.

I would try the following

a)build a list of the commands and put the most common at the beginning, and add a unique number to each i.e.

```
char command_names[] =

"PRESSURE 1"
"LIMIT 2"

;
int command_names_len = sizeof(command_names_str)
```

The C compiler should append these strings for you, so it is easy to move them in a another position

b) these numbers added are an index into a function pointer array, each function should have the same signature, probably that is possible when you allow that some will have unused parameters?
i.e.

```
/* just an example */
void (command*)(int a, int b, int c, int d);

void command_pressure (int a, int b, int c, int d) { }
void command_limit(int a, int b, int c, int d) { }

command commands[] =
( /*notused*/ NULL

, /*     1 */ command_pressure
, /*     2 */ command_limit

);
```

Both lists would match each other visually as well, makes controlling and maintaining it easier. The numbers in the comments are only for help and should match the numbers in the big string build with the function names

Then processing an incoming command is string format is very simple

```
char search_command[20]; /* or whatever the longest command name is */
char* position_of_command = NULL;
int number_of_command = -1;

strncpy( search_command, incomming_command, sizeof(search_command) );
strcat( search_command, " " );  /* must end with blank */

command_position = strnstr( command_names, search_command, command_names_len );
if( command_position != NULL ) {
  position_of_command += strlen(s earch_command) ; /* at beginning of number */
  number_of_command = atoi( position_of_command );
}

if( number_of_command > 0 ) {
  (*commands[number_of_command])(a,0,0,d);
} else {
  /* unknown */
}
```

Some time ago I wrote plain old C, so it might contain syntax error, but that would be the idea.

Advantages:

a) small memory print: no extra pointers or other extra structure overhead to find the command, few programming lines

b) simple to maintain: it is 'table' organized

c) most frequently used commands are handled the fastest!

Disadvantage:

a) keep in mind that commands ending with the same string are not allowed. Can be overcome by adding a blank at the beginning of the names, and also at the search_command. i.e.

```
" PRESSURE 1"
" LIMIT 2"
```

Comment: Wow, very detailed and interesting solution. Thank you! I would not have thought of this. My only slight concern is having to maintain the numbers alongside commands.. if I can insert these automagically then this would be nice.. I don't think this is possible but I do like the idea of combining with [this post](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4408127/Reduce-C-language-coding-errors-with-X-macros--Part-3) or similar..

Comment: The numbers alongside the commands can be non-consecutive, as long as they match the position of the functon pointer in the command table. So adding the name can be in any place, while adding the function pointer is easiest at the end. But I would start with both tables matching their positions, and then gradually over time they divert.

Comment: If it is ok to build the two tables at runtime, then you only have to maintain one table of function calls to a function with two parameters: the name and the pointer to the function. Inside that function, the string can be concatenated and the commands added at the end of the table being build. If you put that in a separate include file, you can compile and run it outside the embedded system, just to see whether the allocated tables are big enough etc. Maybe put a macro around it to avoid that all the command functions must be available - just ignore that parameter in the macro.

Comment: I don't think this works at all, certainly the numerical part of a command cannot be part of the static name of the command? That would mean `LIMIT 1` is distinct from `LIMIT 2` and so on, which seems extremely wasteful and quite annoying.