# Processing ASCII commands in a more robust and type safe way

Tags: c++, serial-port, embedded, ascii

I have a module which receives ASCII commands and then reacts to them accordingly. I am wondering if it is possible, to have a more robust and typesafe way of calling handler functions.

In the past, I had code like the following, which is also very similar to this answer: [Processing ASCII commands via RS232 in embedded c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571866/processing-ascii-commands-via-rs232-in-embedded-c/16572785#16572785)

```
struct Command commands[] = {
{"command1", command1Handler}
{"command2", command2Handler}
 ...
};

//gets called when a new string has been received
void parseCmd(const char *input) {
//find the fitting command entry and call function pointer
}

bool command1Handler(const char *input) { }
bool command2Handler(const char *input) { }
```

I don't like that all handler functions have to do their own parsing. This seems needlessly repetitive and error prone.

It would be cool, if instead we could have it the following way, where all parsing is done in the the parseCmd function:

```
struct Command commands[] = {
{"command1", command1HandlerSafe}
{"command2", command2HandlerSafe}
 ...
};

void parseCmd(const char *input) {
//1. find fitting command entry
//2. check that parameter number fits the expected number for the target function
//3. parse parameters and validate the types
//4. call function with parameters in their correct types
}

bool command1HandlerSafe(bool param1, const char *param2) { }
bool command2HandlerSafe(int param1) {}
```

I think with old C-style varargs it would be possible to do the parsing in a central function, but that would not bring type safety.

Edit:
Meanwhile I came up with the following solution, which I thought somewhat balances the hackiness and modularization:

```
class ParameterSet{

struct Param{
  const char *paramString;
  bool isInt();
  int toInt();
  float toFloat();
  ..
}

ParameterSet(const char *input);
Param at(size_t index);
size_t length();
char m_buffer[100];
Param m_params[10];
}

bool command1HandlerMoreSafe(const ParameterSet *paramSet);
```

Comment: You may find `std::map<std::string, HandlerFunctionType> commands = { {"command1", command1Handler}, { ...}, ... }` useful. You can invoke it with  `commands.at(command)(params)`. [Documentation for `std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: I don't think that is possible, if the command handlers have different signatures. I updated the post in that regard. std::map might still be useful over plain array, though.

Comment: If the handlers have different types you'll have trouble with `struct Command` as well. The function pointer, `std::function` or whatever you used in  `Command` will require all of the handlers to have the same prototype. Unless that whatever has some groovy magic I really want you to let me in on.

Comment: The groovy magic is exactly what I am looking for. One could store the number of parameters and parameter types and then use varargs, but that is not typesafe. :(

Comment: Never use variadic functions for any purpose. It's one of those things that never should have been added to the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building an abstraction layer around this might make things more complex and thereby bug prone. I wouldn't do that unless the amount of commands you are supposed to handle is vast, needs to be maintained, and this is one of the main tasks of your application.

With the pre-requisites to keep type safe and keep parsing separate from algorithms, you could build something similar to the following C-like pseudo code:

```
typedef enum
{
  INT,
  STR
} type_t;                 // for marking which type that is supported by the command

typedef struct
{
  type_t type;
  const char* text;       // what kind of text that is expected in case of strings
} arg_t;

typedef struct
{
  const char* name;       // the name of the command
  arg_t*      args;       // list of allowed arguments
  size_t      args_n;     // size of that list
  void (*callback)(void); // placeholder for callback functions of different types
} command_t;
```

You can then make callback handler functions that aren't concerned about parsing, but only about their dedicated task:

```
void cmd_branch (const char* str);
void cmd_kill   (int n);
```

The array of commands might look something like this:

```
const command_t commands[] = 
{
  { // BRANCH [FAST][SLOW]
    .name="BRANCH", 
    .args=(entry_t[]){ {STR,"FAST"}, {STR,"SLOW"} },
    .args_n=2,
    .callback= (void(*)(void)) cmd_branch,
  },

  { // KILL [7][9]
    .name="KILL",
    .args=(entry_t[]){ {INT, NULL} },
    .args_n=1,
    .callback= (void(*)(void)) cmd_kill,
  }
};
```

The parse function will then do:

- Find which command that was received by searching the above list (bsearch if large list).
- Check what type of arguments the received command supports
- Parse arguments accordingly
- Call the relevant function with arguments of the appropriate type

Since this example just used some dummy type function pointer `(void(*)(void))`, you'll have to cast to the correct type. Can be done by for example C11 _Generic:

```
call(commands[i], int_val);
```

which expands to:

```
#define call(command, arg) _Generic((arg), \
                                    int:         (void(*)(int))         command.callback, \
                                    const char*: (void(*)(const char*)) command.callback )(arg)
```

Comment: Cool stuff, didn't know about _Generic until now. Only limitation seems to be that the number of parameters for the handler functions is fixed?

Comment: @locali You could use a struct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep the command handling interfaces the same is to fall back on the venerable **argv** / **argc** interface that `main()` receives. Assuming the received commands have some notion of *words* (perhaps whitespace separated), it could go like this:

- Receive the input string.
- Parse the input into words where the first word is the name of the command and the remaining words are its arguments.
- As the parsing proceeds, place a pointer to the string that contains each word in an array and keep count of the number of elements in the array.
- Using the first word, look up a command function pointer. You can use something like `bsearch()` if the commands are all known at compile time. Perhaps a hash table might also be appropriate. However you implement the mapping, the result is a pointer to a function that takes an array of pointers to the arguments and a count of the number of elements in the pointer array.
- Invoke the command function via its pointer and pass the array of parsed words and the count, just like `main()` is invoked by startup code.
- From there, each command function can deal with what its arguments specifically mean, converting strings representations to internal forms as necessary.